# Remove duplicate values in JSON Array

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have this value in a field of a SQL Server Table:

```
["I3","I23","B1","B3","B2","B4","B6","I1","I11","I4","I14","I24","I34","I5","I15","I25","I35","I6","I16","I26","I36","I21","B5","I31","I11","I3","I1","I31","I21","I21","I5","I4","I3","I21","I4","I23","B1","I23","I3","B1","B2","B3","I15","I15","B2","I13","I2"]
```

actually it is a `JSON Array`

ome values are present more than 1 time: I need to remove the duplicate `(keeping first occurrence)`
therefore the result should be something like this:

```
["I3","I23","B1","B3","B2","B4","B6","I1","I11","I4","I14","I24","I34","I5","I15","I25","I35","I6","I16","I26","I36","I21","B5","I31","I13","I2"]
```

I've tried several solutions and I seem to be close to solution but in the best solution I got the result as an array of objects instead of array of values:

```
[
     {
        "c": "B1"
     },
     {
        "c": "B2"
     },
     {
        "c": "B3"
     },
     {
        "c": "B4"
     },
     {
        "c": "B5"
     },
     {
        "c": "B6"
     },
     {
        "c": "I1"
     },
     {
        "c": "I11"
     },
     {
        "c": "I13"
     },
     {
        "c": "I14"
     },
     {
        "c": "I15"
     },
     {
        "c": "I16"
     },
     {
        "c": "I2"
     },
     {
        "c": "I21"
     },
     {
        "c": "I23"
     },
     {
        "c": "I24"
     },
     {
        "c": "I25"
     },
     {
        "c": "I26"
     },
     {
        "c": "I3"
     },
     {
        "c": "I31"
     },
     {
        "c": "I34"
     },
     {
        "c": "I35"
     },
     {
        "c": "I36"
     },
     {
        "c": "I4"
     },
     {
        "c": "I5"
     },
     {
        "c": "I6"
     }
  ]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your (not so perfect) solution.

Comment: thanks, but I do not understand your comment: expected result is already present:
what should I add?

Comment: ' what should I add?' - your code attempt. While you are at it add the table definition as text and insert statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disaggregate your values using `OPENJSON`, remove duplicates with `GROUP BY` (taking the min `key` to preserve the order) then aggregate them back up using `STRING_AGG` (there is no in built JSON function to create an array of values AFAIK), so something like this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (JsonArray NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @T (JsonArray) 
VALUES ('["I3","I23","B1","B3","B2","B4","B6","I1","I11","I4","I14","I24","I34","I5","I15","I25","I35","I6","I16","I26","I36","I21","B5","I31","I13","I2"]');

SELECT  t.JsonArray,
        DistinctArray = JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(oj.Value,'"'), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY oj.[Key]), ']'))
FROM    @T AS t
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   SELECT  oj.Value, [Key] = MIN(CONVERT(INT, oj.[Key]))
            FROM    OPENJSON(t.JsonArray) AS oj
            GROUP BY oj.Value
        ) AS oj
GROUP BY t.JsonArray;
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IEHG4LM0)**

Comment: Seems like a missed opportunity by MS....   A simple array without then need for string_agg()

Comment: you might wanna cast the key to INT because i think it doesn't sort correctly otherwise

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - I presume this is what `JSON_ARRAYAGG` will do https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/native-json-type-amp-json-aggregates-are-now-in-private-preview/ba-p/3830753

Comment: @MartinSmith  Good to know that's in the pipeline.

Comment: @siggemannen Good spot, I've updated the answer