# Remove values from JSON array based on values in another table

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I need to remove some values in a JSON array if they match with values from another table, if match id and pax:

Here is some data

```
declare @T1 Table (id int ,pax int ,rooms nvarchar(512))
declare @T2 Table (id int ,pax int ,rooms nvarchar(512))

insert into @T1 (id,pax,rooms)
VALUES (1,3,'["I23","I31","I1","I5","I15","B2","I14","I4","I11","I3","I15","I5","I15","I15","I31","I31","I21","I35","B5-B3","I5-I15","I13","I6-I5-I4-I3","B6","I36-I26-I16-I6"]'),
(1,4,'["I1-I11","I21-I31","I24-I34","B3-B5","B4-B6","I25-I35","I4-I5","I6-I16","I26-I36","I15-I25","I14-I24","I14-I4","I23-I31","I15-I5","I6-I16","I35-I25","I16-I6","I26-I36","B3-B5","B1-B3","I36-I26","I23-I13","B3","I3-I4"]'),
(2,5,'["I4-I5","I1-I11","I21-I31","B4-B6","I15-I25","I6-I16","I26-I36","I31-I23","I23-I13","I11-I21","I35-I25","B5-B3","I14-I4","I24-I34","B3-B1","I5-I15","B2-B4","I24-I14","I5-I3"]')

insert into @T2 (id,pax,rooms)
VALUES (1,3,'["I24-I34-I25-I35-I26-I36"]'), -- not exists
(1,3,'["I36-I26-I16-I6"]'),
(1,3,'["I6-I5-I4-I3"]'),
(1,3,'["I6-I16"]'), --not exists
(1,3,'["B6"]'),
(1,3,'["I13"]'),
(1,4,'["B1-B3"]'),
(1,4,'["B3"]'),
(1,4,'["I3-I4"]'),
(2,5,'["I5-I3"]')
```

So I need to remove from `@T1 with id = 1 and pax=3` the values `"I24-I34-I25-I35-I26-I36"`,`"I36-I26-I16-I6"`,`"I6-I5-I4-I3"`,`"I6-I16"`,`"B6"`,`"I13"` (if exists)

Therefore the expected value will be

```
["I23","I31","I1","I5","I15","B2","I14","I4","I11","I3","I15","I5","I15","I15","I31","I31","I21","I35","B5-B3","I5-I15"]
```

I tried to use the few JSON functions available in SQL Server but clearly my skills are not enough to find the right solution

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT  t1.rooms,
        FilteredArray = JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(oj.Value,'"'), ','), ']'))
FROM    @T1 AS t1
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   SELECT  oj.Value
            FROM    OPENJSON(t1.rooms) AS oj
            join @T2 as t2 on t2.id=t1.id and t2.pax=t1.pax
            where t1.rooms<>t2.rooms
        ) AS oj
        group by t1.rooms
```

But instead of removing values it concatenate 3 times the `@T1` value
Can someone suggest the path to follow to achieve the target?

Comment: This feels somewhat similar to your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77880232/remove-duplicate-values-in-json-array), however, instead of removing the duplicates you need to check if the value is in a different array. You *should* be able to use the answer you got to get you at least 90% of the way there; why didn't your attempt work? What was that attempt?

Comment: yes, right.
Actually I tried and I'm still trying.. but so far no result :-(

Comment: But you haven't included that attempt in your question, Joe . [Edit] the attempt in, *explain* why it didn't work. Tell us what you didn't understand about the prior answer you got and the resources you've read online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Yitzhak's data, perhaps something like:

```sql
SELECT id, pax
    , FilteredArray = JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(oj.Value,'"'), ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CAST([key] AS INT)), ']'))
FROM @T1 AS t1
CROSS APPLY  OPENJSON(t1.rooms) AS oj
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT  1
    FROM    @T2 AS t2
    WHERE   TRIM('["]' FROM t2.rooms) = oj.Value
    AND t2.id = t1.id
    AND t2.pax = t1.pax
)
GROUP BY id, pax;
```

Edit, duplicate removal:

```sql
SELECT  id, pax
,   FilteredArray = JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(Value,'"'), ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY [key]), ']'))
FROM    (
    SELECT  id, pax, value, MIN(CAST([key] AS int)) AS [key]
    FROM    @T1 AS t1
    CROSS APPLY  OPENJSON(t1.rooms) AS oj
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT  1
        FROM    @T2 AS t2
        WHERE   TRIM('["]' FROM t2.rooms) = oj.Value
        AND t2.id = t1.id
        AND t2.pax = t1.pax
    )
    GROUP BY id, pax, value
    ) x
GROUP BY id, pax;
```

Outputs (with dups):

| id | pax | FilteredArray |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | ["I23","I31","I1","I5","I15","B2","I14","I4","I11","I3","I15","I5","I15","I15","I31","I31","I21","I35","B5-B3","I5-I15"] |
| 1 | 4 | ["I1-I11","I21-I31","I24-I34","B3-B5","B4-B6","I25-I35","I4-I5","I6-I16","I26-I36","I15-I25","I14-I24","I14-I4","I23-I31","I15-I5","I6-I16","I35-I25","I16-I6","I26-I36","B3-B5","I36-I26","I23-I13"] |
| 2 | 5 | ["I4-I5","I1-I11","I21-I31","B4-B6","I15-I25","I6-I16","I26-I36","I31-I23","I23-I13","I11-I21","I35-I25","B5-B3","I14-I4","I24-I34","B3-B1","I5-I15","B2-B4","I24-I14"] |

Without dupes:

| id | pax | FilteredArray |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | ["I23","I31","I1","I5","I15","B2","I14","I4","I11","I3","I21","I35","B5-B3","I5-I15"] |
| 1 | 4 | ["I1-I11","I21-I31","I24-I34","B3-B5","B4-B6","I25-I35","I4-I5","I6-I16","I26-I36","I15-I25","I14-I24","I14-I4","I23-I31","I15-I5","I35-I25","I16-I6","I36-I26","I23-I13"] |
| 2 | 5 | ["I4-I5","I1-I11","I21-I31","B4-B6","I15-I25","I6-I16","I26-I36","I31-I23","I23-I13","I11-I21","I35-I25","B5-B3","I14-I4","I24-I34","B3-B1","I5-I15","B2-B4","I24-I14"] |

EXISTS allows more flexibility to handle things that should or should not exist. I also added the ORDER BY for the STRING_AGG to get correct sequence

Comment: yes, thanks.. I was struggling to add an `ORDER BY` to `EXCEPT` but there's no way to do it.
but there is still an issue: Duplicated Values in @T1.rooms, that `EXCEPT` was removing automatically: as you can see in first FilteredArray "I15" is present 4 times (and there are other duplicates)

Comment: I try modifying `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t1.rooms) AS oj` into `CROSS APPLY ( SELECT  oj.Value, [Key] = MIN(CONVERT(INT, oj.[Key]))  FROM    OPENJSON(t1.rooms) AS oj GROUP BY oj.Value    ) AS oj`

Comment: Added another version

Comment: Thanks.. I'll check immediately, since my attempt is not working..:-(

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution based on the set based operator `EXCEPT`.

**SQL #1**

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (id INT ,pax INT ,rooms NVARCHAR(512));
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (id INT ,pax INT ,rooms NVARCHAR(512));

INSERT INTO @T1 (id,pax,rooms)
VALUES (1,3,'["I23","I31","I1","I5","I15","B2","I14","I4","I11","I3","I15","I5","I15","I15","I31","I31","I21","I35","B5-B3","I5-I15","I13","I6-I5-I4-I3","B6","I36-I26-I16-I6"]'),
(1,4,'["I1-I11","I21-I31","I24-I34","B3-B5","B4-B6","I25-I35","I4-I5","I6-I16","I26-I36","I15-I25","I14-I24","I14-I4","I23-I31","I15-I5","I6-I16","I35-I25","I16-I6","I26-I36","B3-B5","B1-B3","I36-I26","I23-I13","B3","I3-I4"]'),
(2,5,'["I4-I5","I1-I11","I21-I31","B4-B6","I15-I25","I6-I16","I26-I36","I31-I23","I23-I13","I11-I21","I35-I25","B5-B3","I14-I4","I24-I34","B3-B1","I5-I15","B2-B4","I24-I14","I5-I3"]');

INSERT INTO @T2 (id,pax,rooms)
VALUES (1,3,'["I24-I34-I25-I35-I26-I36"]'), -- not exists
(1,3,'["I36-I26-I16-I6"]'),
(1,3,'["I6-I5-I4-I3"]'),
(1,3,'["I6-I16"]'), --not exists
(1,3,'["B6"]'),
(1,3,'["I13"]'),
(1,4,'["B1-B3"]'),
(1,4,'["B3"]'),
(1,4,'["I3-I4"]'),
(2,5,'["I5-I3"]');

-- Method #1
WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT t1.id, t1.pax, oj.Value
    FROM  @T1 AS t1
    CROSS APPLY  OPENJSON(t1.rooms) AS oj
    EXCEPT
    SELECT t2.id, t2.pax, TRIM('["]' FROM t2.rooms)
    FROM @T2 AS t2
)
SELECT rs.id, rs.pax
    , FilteredArray = JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(rs.Value,'"'), ','), ']'))
FROM rs
GROUP BY rs.id, rs.pax;
```

**Output**

| id | pax | FilteredArray |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | ["B2","B5-B3","I1","I11","I14","I15","I21","I23","I3","I31","I35","I4","I5","I5-I15"] |
| 1 | 4 | ["B3-B5","B4-B6","I14-I24","I14-I4","I15-I25","I15-I5","I16-I6","I1-I11","I21-I31","I23-I13","I23-I31","I24-I34","I25-I35","I26-I36","I35-I25","I36-I26","I4-I5","I6-I16"] |
| 2 | 5 | ["B2-B4","B3-B1","B4-B6","B5-B3","I11-I21","I14-I4","I15-I25","I1-I11","I21-I31","I23-I13","I24-I14","I24-I34","I26-I36","I31-I23","I35-I25","I4-I5","I5-I15","I6-I16"] |

**SQL #2**

Obviously, SQL #1 is set based. Sets are inherently unordered.

Here is another method that keeps initial JSON array ordered after removal not needed entries.

It is based on SQL Server's XML and XQuery powerful functionality.

It preserves duplicate entries based on your desired output.

```
-- Method #2
DECLARE @separator CHAR(3) = '","';

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT id, pax
        , (
        SELECT TRIM('["]' FROM rooms)
        FROM @t2 AS c
        WHERE c.id = p.id AND c.pax = p.pax
        FOR XML PATH('r'), ROOT('remove')
    ) AS remove
    FROM @T2 AS p
    GROUP BY id, pax
), base AS
(
    SELECT t.id, t.pax, c
    FROM  @T1 AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT '<base><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(TRIM('["]' FROM rooms), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></base>') AS t1(c)
)
SELECT b.id, b.pax --, t2.x
    , filteredArray = CONCAT('["', REPLACE(t2.x.query('
        for $x in /root/base/r
        where not($x = (/root/remove/r))
        return data($x)
    ').value('.', ' NVARCHAR(512)'),SPACE(1),'","'), '"]')
FROM base AS b
    INNER JOIN rs ON (rs.id = b.id AND rs.pax = b.pax)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root>' + b.c + rs.remove + '</root>' AS XML)) AS t2(x);
```

**Output**

| id | pax | filteredArray |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | ["I23","I31","I1","I5","I15","B2","I14","I4","I11","I3","I15","I5","I15","I15","I31","I31","I21","I35","B5-B3","I5-I15"] |
| 1 | 4 | ["I1-I11","I21-I31","I24-I34","B3-B5","B4-B6","I25-I35","I4-I5","I6-I16","I26-I36","I15-I25","I14-I24","I14-I4","I23-I31","I15-I5","I6-I16","I35-I25","I16-I6","I26-I36","B3-B5","I36-I26","I23-I13"] |
| 2 | 5 | ["I4-I5","I1-I11","I21-I31","B4-B6","I15-I25","I6-I16","I26-I36","I31-I23","I23-I13","I11-I21","I35-I25","B5-B3","I14-I4","I24-I34","B3-B1","I5-I15","B2-B4","I24-I14"] |

Comment: Thanks, it works, but has an unwanted side effect... it sorts the @T1.rooms values, while I need to keep the sequence:

I've modified the query adding a key, but the problem is that I need to add a value in the EXCEPT  that match with the oj.[key] but do not know where to get it

Comment: `;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT t1.id, t1.pax, oj.Value, MIN(convert(int,oj.[Key])) k
    FROM  @T1 AS t1
    CROSS APPLY  OPENJSON(t1.rooms) AS oj
 GROUP BY t1.id,t1.pax,oj.Value 
    EXCEPT
    SELECT t2.id, t2.pax, TRIM('["]' FROM t2.rooms), 1
    FROM @T2 AS t2 
)

SELECT rs.id, rs.pax
    , FilteredArray = JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(rs.Value,'"'), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY k), ']'))
FROM rs
GROUP BY rs.id, rs.pax;`

Comment: I put a "1" as key but clearly does not work: it correctly keep the sequence but does not remove the EXCEPT: can pls suggest a path to the solution?